# Confusion about bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Closed and bounded intervals are compact. Let $a,b\in R$, then the metric space $([a,b], usual  metric)$ is compact.

In the proof, it was said that $(x_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence in $[a,b]$. Then $(x_{n})_{n}$ is bounded.

I am unsure of why this last part is true. Why is the sequence bounded? It was not stated that it was convergent. Is it to do with the interval or the closed subset of R?

Comment: Do you know the _definition_ of "$(x_n)_n$ is bounded"???

Comment: Yes! I realize I confused bounded sequences with bounded sequence of functions.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$a \le x_n \le b$$

for all $n$. Hence $a$ is a lower bound of $(x_{n})_{n}$ and $b$ is an upper bound of $(x_{n})_{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is bounded if there exist $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha \leq x_n \leq \beta, \forall n$. This is obviously true in this case, since $a \leq x_n \leq b$.